# How can we rank contacts in league tables based on 'points' for completing Activities, attending Events, having a Membership, etc - "gameify" CiviCRM?

Tags: civievent, civicontribute, civimember, activities

I want to create "league tables" (rankings based on "points") - similar to the user rankings that Stack Exchange uses - for contacts who have participated in Events, completed various Activities, have Membership(s), made other Contributions, etc.

Completing different actions would have different, weighted points - for example, an organization might value attending a political action, or signing an online petition, or voting, more highly than merely having a Membership or just contributing money otherwise.

It seems relatively simple - assigning the points to the Activities, Event participation, etc in back-end tables and adding custom fields, then creating Reports using current capabilities with some slight tweaking.

Rankings based on weighted points *could* be more objective than merely assigning a leadership/engagement value (like 1,2,3,4,5 with 1 being better/most, 5 the least) to a contact, which can be somewhat subjective.

Has anyone done something like this using Civi? Would be great to know.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Joe, just wanted to let you know that there has been some more development on this since the question was answered. There is now a branch with a report template that allows showing and ordering by points.

Comment: @DaveFF thanks so much, will check it out! Was ill for awhile and still plowing through a backlog of stuff on my to do list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the author of CiviPoints that John and Erik mentioned. We have a points system internally at Future First for tracking engagement, and then colour codes based on that for reporting. Currently it's being done with spreadsheets.

Some development was done before the sprint on the database structure and API for this extension, and a basic UI including contact tabs. Hearing more about CiviRules at CiviCon and the sprint I thought it would be a great idea for automating our weekly figures. I'm interested in integrating it with CiviRules as both a trigger (when some level of points is hit, do X) and an action (when Y happens, grant some points). There's a preliminary version of the action part in a branch.

I haven't done anything on it since the sprint, and it's not in production or automatic distribution, because our main priority has been working on a new portal for our members. I do hope to give it more attention soon though!

League tables aren't something I've considered before, but sounds like a good idea. Some features it does have, in the underlying structure at least, are point-in-time history, and support for multiple points types (different programmes, or maybe engagement tracking as well as some sort of credits).

Some issues/enhancements are listed on GitHub. Please feel free to use it and test it, any feedback would be welcome. Thanks!

Comment: @DaveFF sounds really interesting and useful even as a work in progress! Looking forward to learning more and contributing if my chops are up to it.

Comment: hey, do you know if there is a "wiki" on how to use CiviPoints? I am trying it on the latest 5.x version and don't see the options after installing.

Comment: @Devaroop No wiki or other official docs from me apart from what's in the repo. I'm not maintaining our Civi stuff any more officially, as we stopped using Civi in 2016. JohnFF might still be doing Civi work though.

Answer (score 2):

Following from ErikH's answer, the repo is here: https://github.com/futurefirst/uk.org.futurefirst.networks.civipoints

There's fledgling CiviRules integration that hasn't been merged. CiviRules will allow you to build the conditions necessary to award points. For instance, attending a certain type of event gives 5 points, having a certain type of activity or a certain value in a custom field gives 10 points etc.

The extra neat thing is that points can expire. I.e. if you want to track engagement over time, a volunteer who did a shift 10 years ago isn't as engaged as one who has done one earlier in the month.

If you were to:
   1. install, use, and test and 
   2. write instructions that might be a really handy contribution :)

(PS: I've brought the author DaveFF's attention to this, although I haven't contributed to this code myself. I've no idea if it's currently in active use or not, but I've seen it working on a local install).

Comment: thanks so much will test on my staging site and offer suggestions in the GitHub repo issues, maybe even a PR or two :). Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I know someone at [Future First](http://futurefirst.org.uk/) is working on the same kiond of idea, combining it with the [CiviRules](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civirules) extension

Comment: Thanks ErikH - could they jump in here, possibly? Would love to learn more.

Comment: That would be good indeed, but I am not regularly in contact with them, just picked it up at the Edale sprint. I will see what I can find out and ask them to react to this post.